# How to rollback to previous state after user submits a wrong email in a form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created a js script to validate an email input. When the user inputs a string which doesn't have the form of an email, the text turns red.

I want to know how can I make the text get back to it's previous state, where it wasn't red, after the user has submitted the wrong string and wants to submit again. 
I want the text to stay red just until the user starts typing again.

Here is my code:

```
$('.submit').bind("click", function(e){
    var error = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('.email').val();          
    if(!validateEmail(email) || email === "" ){
        $(".email").addClass('error')//this class makes my text red
        $(".email").focus();
        error = error + 1;
        console.log (error)

        return false
    } else {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'email.php',
           data: {
            email: email
           }, // serializes the form's elements.
         });
    }
    // $(".email").removeClass('error');
    // if(error === 1)
    // {
        // $(".email").removeClass('error');

    // }        
})
```

Comment: Just remove the error class on the document ready.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".email" ).keypress(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("error");
});
```

So when you start typing it will remove the error class.

You might just add the same line with .change instead of .keypress so pasting an email will also clear the error.

The other answer is kinda better I guess, but if you'd go for that way I'd implement an else statement to add the error class since now it will switch to normal but if you make an invalid email it will remain that way.

Comment: +1. I think it'd be better to bind the contents of that `else` statement you mentioned to an `onblur` event. That way the user doesn't get an error while in the middle of typing their email.

Comment: Well this is what I needed, the keypress thing. Thank you sir!

Comment: Good that you're helped you can accept one of the answers if it's all working.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will bind an event to when the user types into the input. It will not remove the red border until the change formulates a *valid* email. Simply remove the `if` statement if you'd like it to remove the red border regardless.

```
$('.email').keyup(function() {
    if (validateEmail($(this).val()) {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
});
```